# How do I clear gmake error (e=2) on Mingw64?

Tags: mingw, gnu-make, build-error

Getting an odd make error in Mingw64.  I tried adding my ExtraPutty install location.  No joy.  Running GNU Make 3.81.  My makefile is pretty straightforward.  Any ideas?

```
INCDIR = inc/pvt inc/pub
SRCDIR = src
OBJDIR = obj
LIBDIR = lib

CC=gcc
CFLAGS := $(foreach d, $(INCDIR), -I$d) -fmax-errors=3 -std=c11

_SRC = main.c
_OBJ := $(subst $(SRCDIR),$(OBJDIR),$(_SRC:%.c=%.o))
OBJ := $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

test: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    @mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

$(OBJ): $(DEPS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -rm -r $(OBJDIR)/*
```

Here's the complete error that I'm getting:

> $ make
> gcc -c -o obj/main.o src/main.c  -Iinc/pvt  -Iinc/pub -fmax-errors=3 -std=c11
> process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, gcc -c -o obj/main.o src/main.c -Iinc/pvt -Iinc/pub -fmax-errors=3 -std=c11, ...) failed.
> make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
> make: *** [obj/main.o] Error 2

Comment: Please include (copy and paste, with formatting) the exact, complete error you get.  `e=2` just means something exited with an exit code of 2, which make treats as an error.  The only way to solve the problem is look at the rest of the error messages to see what failed.

Comment: @MadScientist Sorry, I added it to the original post.

Comment: So, your compiler (`gcc`) is not present on your system or, if it is, it isn't present in your `PATH` so the shell can't find it.  Are you sure that your compiler is actually named `gcc` and not something else?  If you run `gcc` from your shell prompt directly does it work?  If it doesn't work there it can't work from within your makefile either.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks.  It took some effort, but I finally figured out how to install gcc on Windows. https://www.devdungeon.com/content/install-gcc-compiler-windows-msys2-cc